# What is Dijkstra's Minimum Spanning Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm having trouble finding an example algorithm for Dijkstra's Minimum Spanning tree. I already know about Dijkstra's Single Shortest Path algorithm, but not the spanning tree. I have the simple explanation from class which is this:

> For each edge, add it to the tree. If a cycle is detected, remove the heaviest edge.

I've scoured the Internet and I couldn't find an algorithm for it.

I might need to just code it for myself, but I thought I would ask if anyone has a good example.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Probably because it's more commonly known as [Prim's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).

Comment: @StoryTeller No I don't think so. In particular I don't know of any algorithm that _removes_ edges -- neither Kruskal nor Prim ('s algorithm) do that.

Comment: @user202729 - Well, I know only one algorithm for finding a MST, that is attributed to Dijkstra. Either way the OP's class material seems inaccurate.

Comment: Is this also known as steiner tree problem? If so have a look at https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.net.steiner.html, I think it's no problem to find the sources as well

Comment: Could it be Reverse-delete algorithm https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-delete_algorithm?

Comment: There is no such thing. Dijkstra is the shortest path algorithm.

Comment: There are two popular MST algorithms: Kruskal's and Prim's. Neither is the one you described. There is a variant of Dijkstra's Shortest Path that, given a source node, finds the shortest paths from it to *all* nodes in a graph, but this is not a Minimum Spanning Tree.

Comment: Dijkstra's Shortest Path is used as replacement of MST to avoid cycling messages throughout the network like WiMaX and some military radio-based networks. I guess that's where confusion comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

[image]

The algorithm works as follows:

1. The graph has gray edges.
2. Adding some edges without detecting a circle.
3. After adding the vertical edge, the algorithm detects a circle. It removes the last edge (red) because it has the heaviest weight.
4. Adding the horizontal edge produces a circle, too. Since it has the heaviest weight it is removed.
5. Adding the last edge will also produce a circle, but the last edge added hasn't the heaviest weight. Instead the edge with weight 3 must be removed. The Minimal Spanning Tree consists of the black coloured edges in picture (5).

If you are marking the visiting nodes, circle detection is easy. To find the heaviest edge of a detected circle, you use a common search algorithm for circles.

**Note**: Picture (5) demonstrates why it is necessary to visit all edges, because (3) already contains a Spanning Tree. But it is not minimal.